# JavaScript what is causing 'undefined' in my code?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I started learning JavaScript a few days ago and one of for loops in a simple piece of code I am writing is causing an `undefined` in an alert.
I do understand that this is an outcome of a variable of an undefined type. 
The problem is I don't know which part of my code I have to fix.
Here is an affected piece of code:

```
var message;   
for (var songs = 0; songs < playlist.length; songs++) {
    message += '\n' + (songs+1) + '. ' + playlist[songs] + '\n';
}

alert(message);
```

It displays the `undefined` right above the line with a first element of `playlist` array.

I tried deleting elements of `message` variable one at a time to check which one could have caused it.
I also tried adding: `message = String(message);`after a for loop.

I will really appreciate a help / explanation for my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't initialized your `message` variable with a value, so it is `undefined`.

Set it to an initial value, like so:

```
var message = '';
```

Comment: Nice catch, this is the problem for sure.

Comment: Thank you very much Wrokar. This was it!

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `message` as an undefined value, and then add to it -- resulting in the string "undefined" when that value is coerced into a string.

Instead, try initializing it as an empty string:

```js
var playlist = ["foo","bar","bar"] 

var message = "";   // <-- here
for (var songs = 0; songs < playlist.length; songs++) {
    message += '\n' + (songs+1) + '. ' + playlist[songs] + '\n';
}

alert(message);
```

Comment: "You initialize message as a null value" — No. It is `undefined`. That is different to `null`.

Comment: You're right, sloppy terminology on my part. Will correct.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! Your answer is very helpful and informative. I have chosen Wrokar's answer as the best this time as it seems clearer in its simplicity.